# Sails.js: How to find records based on values in associated collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm looking for a way to make sub-query using Sails.js Waterline. The record has an association with Charge model.

I would expect something like that to work, but that doesn't seem to be supported:

```
var topRecords = await Record.find({'charge.paid':true});
```

The closest I got was this:

```
var topRecords = await Record.find().populate('charge',{paid:true});
```

but the problem is that it still returns all the Records regardless, just doesn't populate the records that do not match populate where statement.

The reason why I can't search for charges first is that I want to sort the data based on one of the values in Record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the `Charge`s then use `.map` to get the records from there.

```
const topCharges = await Charge.find({ paid: true }).populate('records');
const topRecords = topCharges.map(charge => charge.record);
```

Comment: how would you then sort topRecords based on likes in Records collection or CreatedAt?

Comment: I have achieved sorting with lodash! Ignore my comment